# Handling concurrent file writes

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, concurrency

I am developing an ASP.NET application that takes user input and serializes them into a text file. Now, when a second update request comes while the file is still being written, an IOException will be generated.

How do I handle concurrent update request to this file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can implement a Producer - Consumer, Where the main thread adds the object to a Queue, and the Consumer writes the Queue to the Disk.

Comment: This is better than using lock because the writing threads will not be blocked. You can use a thread safe queue for log messages and run a separate background thread to consume the queue and write the messages to the file. Then in the consumer you can also implement functionality like rolling over the files etc.

Comment: This works great until someone hits CTRL+C and all the data in your queue is thrown to the wind instead of your file system.

Answer (score 0):

Use the lock it will solve

```
 lock (this)
```

{
serializes them into a text file
}